# Shiny modules and data.table filter: not working as expected

Tags: r, shiny, data.table

I am trying develope an app with shiny modules and data.table, but I can not figure out how to get it working. 
An small example, is the following app which receives as arguments of the module a data.table, a variable and a cut value and should print all some result based on filtering the data.table using the arguments.

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)

name <-c('a','b','c','d','e')
value <- c(2,4,6,8,10)
data <- data.table(name,value)

# MODULE UI
test_UI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  textOutput(ns("test"))
}

# MODULE Server
test_OUT <- function(input, output, session, df, var, x) {
  output$test <- renderText({    
    d <- df[var > x, ]
    print(unique(d$name))
  })
}

# App ui 
ui <- fluidPage(
  test_UI("test")
)

# App server
server <- function(input, output,session){  
  callModule(test_OUT, "test", data, 'value', 6)
}

# App
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The result is :

```
> a b c d e
```

When it is supposed to be:

```
> d e
```

I know if I use dplyr or other method of filtering, this should work, but I need data.table for perfomance, as I am dealing with very big datasets.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make it work using "get" .

I replaced the line:

```
  d <- df[var > x, ]
```

with

```
 d <- df[get(var) > x, ]
```

and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

The reason this doesn't work is because `data.table` uses itself as an environment. So

```
df[var > x, ]
```

looks for a column named `var` (note: not the value of `var`, but `df[["var"]]`) and doesn't see it, then looks in the parent environment (the `test_OUT` function) and now does find it. And it's the character vector `"value"`.

So, since `x == 6`, the comparison is `"value" > 6` which is `TRUE`. That's why you're getting every row.

To get more info on how `data.table` works, you should read the documentation: `?data.table`.  It's actually pretty good.

For your problem, replace

```
d <- df[var > x, ]
```

with

```
d <- df[df[[var]] > x, ]
```

`df[[var]]` uses the list-style subsetting by name.

Comment: thanks Nathan! I will check data.table docs. I have learned it "by doing" in a very messy way. Do you see any issues with the "get" solution? thanks again.

Comment: `get` can lead to unexpected behavior since it can also look outside the data.table.  For example, if the variable `foo` is assigned in `test_OUT`, and somebody calls the module with `var = "foo"`, then `get(var)` returns `foo`, but `df[[var]]` returns `NULL`.